# Connection to FTP server sometimes works and others not

Tags: ftp, filezilla, proftpd

I have a ubuntu server (on Azure) running proftpd, when I try to connect to that server using FileZilla sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (usually it doesn't work at first... and I need to keep trying several random times before it works... and once it does it works for good...), now this is the error I receive it FileZilla logs:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.myserver.com
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command:    USER my_user
Response:   331 Password required for my_user
Command:    PASS *******
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of ftp.myserver.com
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (Debian) [xx.xx.xx.xx]
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   500 AUTH not understood
Command:    AUTH SSL
Response:   500 AUTH not understood
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command:    USER my_user
Response:   331 Password required for my_user
Command:    PASS *******
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

and this is what I see in proftpd logs:

```
2016-08-09 10:26:37,263 FTP proftpd[33961] 10.0.0.6 (yy.yy.yy.yy[yy.yy.yy.yy]): USER my_user: Login successful.
2016-08-09 10:26:37,264 FTP proftpd[33961] 10.0.0.6 (yy.yy.yy.yy[yy.yy.yy.yy]): FTP session closed.
2016-08-09 10:26:37,468 FTP proftpd[33970] 10.0.0.6 (yy.yy.yy.yy[yy.yy.yy.yy]): FTP session opened.
```

I don't know why the server closes and reopens the connection after the login but I am no FTP expert...

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

**Edit:**

[This is the content of proftpd.conf file](http://pastebin.com/LUz690up)

Comment: The `mod_delay` module can be a common cause of delays; see [its FAQ](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_delay.html#FAQ).

Comment: Thank you @Castaglia, in fact I found that mod_delay enabled, unfortunately disabling it did not solve the issue

Comment: Could you provide the full `proftpd.conf` (minus any sensitive passwords) that you are using, so that we can see what else might be causing the delay?

Comment: Sure, I edited my post with link to the content

Comment: In that config, `DelayEngine on` is seen, rather than `DelayEngine off`; I was expecting to see it disabled.  Also, are there any config files under `/etc/proftpd/conf.d/`, pulled in via the `Include` at the end, which define any virtual hosts?  Lastly, you might check your `/etc/pam.d/ftp` configuration, to see if any PAM modules might be affecting this.  (Alternatively, you could try turning off PAM, via `AuthPAM off`, to check whether PAM is involved in this delay.)

Comment: I just turned `DelayEngine` back on when turning it off didn't solve the issue... there is no other config file under `/etc/proftpd/conf.d/`. I will check that PAM module

Comment: Oh! it seems like it was really PAM... I turned it off as you said with `AuthPAM off` and now the server responds fast!

Comment: Can you make an answer in order to accept it? Thanks a lot for the big help... that issue was really annoying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple possible causes for a delay at login time with ProFTPD.  The most common causes are the `mod_delay` module (see [its FAQ](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_delay.html#FAQ)), *or* [`IdentLookups`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_ident.html#IdentLookups) or [`UseReverseDNS`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_UseReverseDNS.html).

However, since *your* delay happens after the `PASS` command has been sent, that rules out the `IdentLookups` or `UseReverseDNS` directives, as those pertain to the initial connection establishment, before any commands are sent.

Per discussion with the reporter, any latency added by `mod_delay` was ruled out.  That leaves PAM, which, depending on the configuration (*e.g.* in `/etc/pam.d/ftp`) and the modules used, can add its own latency (over which ProFTPD has little control).  To disable ProFTPD's use of PAM, you would use the following in the config:

```
<IfModule mod_auth_pam.c>
  AuthPAM off
</IfModule>
```

The reporter mentioned that disabling the use of PAM did indeed remove the delay -- thus pointing out that one of the PAM modules was the root cause.

Hope this helps!